# Calculate route laps with Neo4j and cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and just investigating whether it fits my needs. Having the following graph:

```
CREATE (a:Stop {name: 'A'})-[:ROUTE {dist: 1}]->(b:Stop {name: 'B'})
CREATE (a)-[:ROUTE {dist: 4}]->(c:Stop {name: 'C'})
CREATE (a)-[:ROUTE {dist: 10}]->(d:Stop {name: 'D'})
CREATE (b)-[:ROUTE {dist: 3}]->(e:Stop {name: 'E'})
CREATE (c)-[:ROUTE {dist: 4}]->(d)
CREATE (c)-[:ROUTE {dist: 2}]->(f:Stop {name: 'F'})
CREATE (d)-[:ROUTE {dist: 1}]->(e)
CREATE (e)-[:ROUTE {dist: 3}]->(b)
CREATE (e)-[:ROUTE {dist: 2}]->(a)
CREATE (f)-[:ROUTE {dist: 1}]->(d)
```

[image]

How can I create say some bicycle routes which are limited to a specified mileage? Say I want to get all possible routes from 'E' to 'E' with an overall mileage of less than 16 with the allowance of duplication of any node to node relationships. The result should be something like this:

`|---------------|---------|
    | Route         | Mileage |
    |---------------|---------|
    | E-A-B-E       |   6     |
    | E-A-B-E-B-E   |   15    |
    | E-A-B-E-A-B-E |   12    |
    | ...           |         |`

The main point is to get duplication of routes, the laps, like E-A-B-E-A-B-E. Is this possible to do with cypher only or there is a better approach like getting all the unique routes by cypher and then calculate possible laps somehow on the backend? From my experiments, I couldn't make cypher to traverse the same nodes twice or more time.

Answer (score 1):

Cypher has an inherent restriction on uniqueness, but it isn't based on nodes, it doesn't prevent revisiting of nodes. It prevents traversing the same relationships more than once per path. This is why you can't do `E-A-B-E-B-E`, because this would traverse the `B-E` relationship more than once.

The primary reason for this behavior is to prevent infinite loops when performing variable-length expansions, and that's a very real risk for you if you need a different form of traversal uniqueness that allows repeated traversal of both nodes and relationships.

While APOC Procedures has path expander procedures that can use different traversal uniquenesses, you would almost certainly encounter an infinite loop unless you set a maximum number of hops. Currently path expanders cannot do property access, so you couldn't sum up property values and stop at certain thresholds.